# Who are these classic DC characters?

Tags: dc, character-identification

I saw this T-shirt in store yesterday, and realized I couldn't recognize a good number of the villains, and a couple heroes. They're too early in comic history for me to be familiar with them.

[image]

**Who are they, and from what comic line are they known for (if not their own)?**
If it helps, these characters all seem to have appeared in the early 1980s (such as Cyborg) or earlier. As of yet, I've seen nothing later than Cyborg.

**Update:** I've found some, and posted them in an answer. Those now circled I'm unable to find or even know where to start looking.

---

These are those I know, left to right starting from the top:

- Red Tornado
- Robin
- Captain Marvel
- Mister Mxyzpltk
- The Riddler
- The Penguin
- Martian Manhunter
- Lex Luthor (in armor)
- Kid Flash
- The Joker
- Hawkman
- Green Arrow
- Cyborg
- Darkseid
- Elongated Man
- Dr. Fate
- Aquaman
- Firestorm
- Batman
- Beast Boy
- Superman
- The Flash
- Green Lantern

Comment: Top row, third from left is Captain Marvel Junior.

Comment: Right side, third from the front, bald guy with glasses and white coat, is Captain Marvel's archenemy, Dr. Sivana.

Comment: On the left side, second and third from the bottom: is that… Xena and… Robin Hood?!? (Also -1 for missing hand-drawn circles! :-p)

Comment: Among the ones you can't recognize, how do you know which ones are villains and which are heroes?

Comment: @user14111 Speculation based on classic design elements used for good guys and bad guys. There's a few I really have no idea about. Also, some of what I believe are good guys are smiling, such as the guy above Aquaman.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, now I've got some Paint-drawn circles!

Comment: Nightwing - http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/d/d3/Nightwing_0010.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111009075846

Comment: To clarify @DavidBanner's comment, the guy with the face mask between The Penguin and the armored Lex Luther is Nightwing, in his original costume, from when he first changed from being Robin (Dick Grayson).

Comment: @Kaine That's a parademon. Luthor's on the left.

Comment: I wonder if the police officer is supposed to be Blackhawk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhawk_(DC_Comics)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are all characters from the [Super Powers cartoon series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Super_Powers_Team:_Galactic_Guardians). I found a clearer image at Target.com, so here's everyone on the shirt.

[image]

And who they are:

1. Tyr
2. Steppenwolf
3. Captain Marvel Jr.
4. Red Tornado
5. Robin
6. General Zod
7. Orion
8. Samurai
9. Mantis
10. Nightwing
11. Martian Manhunter
12. Mister Miracle
13. Mr. Mxyzptlk
14. Captain Marvel
15. Riddler
16. Parademon
17. Penguin
18. Golden Pharaoh
19. Brainiac
20. Robotman
21. Elongated Man
22. Hawkman
23. Joker
24. Kid Flash
25. Kalibak
26. Lex Luthor
27. Green Arrow
28. Mr Freeze
29. Cyborg
30. Changeling
31. Darkseid
32. Dr Fate
33. Dr Sivana
34. DeSaad
35. Cyclotron (holding his detachable face)
36. Green Lantern
37. Flash
38. Superman
39. Batman
40. Firestorm
41. El Dorado
42. Aquaman

Comment: Interesting! The Mantis is called a green Parademon in other stuff I found.  Any explanation?

Comment: I'd never heard of this cartoon, so thanks for the find.

Comment: @CreationEdge, all of the images I can find for "green parademon" aren't actually the same character, though there are similarities. This is definitely Mantis, though. See here: http://www.kennersuperpowers.com/spfigures/mantis.html

Comment: Tyr (#1) actually originated as a character in the Legion of Super-Heroes comic. If anyone's wondering why many of the New Gods characters don't resemble their typical appearances as seen in DC comic books, it's because Mattel paid Jack Kirby a designer's commission to re-design his characters for action figures. This was many years after Kirby had first designed those characters for comic books. Some of the characters (Mr. Miracle, Darkseid) were hardly changed at all, but some (like Mantis and the Parademon) were more radically revised.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the start of an answer, thanks so far to @user14111

- Steppenwolf (Tracked him down because I remember seeing [the toy](http://gofigureactionfigures.com/media/steppenwolf-dcu.jpg)) - See below
- Captain Marvel Junior (user14111) - Captain Marvel
- Dr. Sivana Sr (user14111) - Captain Marvel
- Brainiac (the silver robot, middle of the rightmost column) - Superman
- [Robotman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotman_(Cliff_Steele))

  Finding Steppenwolf led me to the New Gods of Apokolips:

[image]

- Darkseid (already known)
- Steppenwolf
- Parademon (Green)
- Parademon (Red, looks bat-faced)
- Desaad (purple robe here, but red on the T-shirt)
- Kalibak (guy with crazy hair)
- Mr. Freeze!
- Tyr

Finding these guys lead me to *Death of the New Gods*, revealing:

- Mister Miracle:
  [image]

And that's where I hit a wall, although I've ruled out anyone else in the [Legion of Superheroes](http://s14.photobucket.com/user/mgrabois/media/misc_LSH/long_poster.jpg.html)